# How can I create a server Protocol class with an __init__ function?

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I come from a Twisted background, so I have a solid understanding of protocols and factories, as implemented by Twisted.  However, I am in the midst of switching over to asyncio, and I'm having a bit of trouble understanding how factories integrate into this particular framework.

In the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-server-protocol), we have an example of a server's `asyncio.Protocol` class definition.  It does not have a user-defined `__init__` function, so we can simply call `loop.create_server(EchoServerClientProtocol, addr, port)`.

What happens if our `Protocol` needs to implement some initialization logic?  For instance, consider this example which sets a maximum buffer size:

```
import asyncio
from collections import deque

class BufferedProtocolExample(asyncio.Protocol):
    def __init__(self, buffsize=None):
        self.queue = deque((), buffsize)

    # ...
```

In Twisted, you'd create a `Factory` class to hold all of the configuration values, which you would then pass to the function initializing the connection.  Asyncio [seems to work in the same way](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_server), but I cannot find any documentation.

I *could* use `functools.partial`, but what is the correct way of handling this case?

Comment: The documentation [has an example where they use a lambda for this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client-protocol), so my guess is that `functools.partial` is fine. They also [state that `protocol_factory` can be any callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#creating-connections).

Comment: @Phillip Thank you very much.  Feel free to restate this as an answer and I'll gladly accept.

Comment: [create_connection](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_connection) and [create_server](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#asyncio.BaseEventLoop.create_server) both end up running `protocol = protocol_factory()` (see the code [here](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/4f45ac71aa8e1aa97007c6da4f12f7c159b24a36/asyncio/selector_events.py#L198) and [there](https://github.com/python/asyncio/blob/27f3499f968e8734fef91677eb339b5d32a6f675/asyncio/base_events.py#L681)).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation [has an example where they use a lambda for this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-protocol.html#tcp-echo-client-protocol), so my guess is that functools.partial is fine. They also [state that `protocol_factory` can be any callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-eventloop.html#creating-connections). So to have something like Twisted's Factorys, you'll just need to implement `__call__` on a class the way you'd implement `buildProtocol` in Twisted.